# table_cache NOT set inside my.cnf file, what are the risks?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I just found that table_cache option is not set inside my.cnf Mysql settings page.
Can this represent a problem? 
How could i benefit from setting a value <> 0 inside the my.cnf file? What could be a suggested value?

Some useful parameters currently in place in the system are these one:

```
| Variable_name            | Value   
 -------------------------------------
| Com_show_open_tables     | 5       |

| Open_table_definitions   | 500     |

| Open_tables              | 390     |

| Opened_table_definitions | 604     |

| Opened_tables            | 5120350 |

| Slave_open_temp_tables   | 0       |
```

Comment: "table_cache"? What is your version?

Comment: mysql version is 5.6

Comment: AFAIK `table_cache` doesn't exist since like version 5.1.